# Закрасить половину окна java swing

Tags: java, swing

Как можно закрасить только половину JFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать растянуть панель на половину окна с помощью setBounds().

А если понадобится закрасить вторую половину другим цветом то можно сделать несколько панелей.

Comment: Сделал через несколько панелей.

Comment: так тоже можно.